# How do I put the induvidual digits from 0 to 9 from a bigger number into an array containing only digits

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to push all the individual digits of BigNumber into an array called IndividualNumber. (See code below.) Somehow the code that I try to use doesn't work. It doesn't push the digits into the array. Can someone please explain me why not?

```
int BigNumber = 2639;
array IndividualNumber;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  IndividualNumber.push(BigNumber[i]);
}

//IndividualNumber should be [2, 6, 3, 9].
```

Thank you in advance and have a nice day.

Comment: What language are you writing this in? It doesn't appear to be C or C++.

Comment: This is written using arduino.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems with this code:

1. `BigNumber` is an integer but you are trying to index it like an array or pointer. One way to get the digits of a number in base 10 is to take the remainder when divided by powers of 10.
2. In C++ (which is used with Arduino), arrays have to be declared with a type and a capacity. The correct way to declare `IndividualNumber` with a capacity of 10 numbers for example would be something like:

   ```
   int Individual[10];
   ```
3. To set i-th element of the array you use the following syntax:

   ```
   IndividualNumber[i] = ...
   ```

With these corrected, a possible solution might look something like:

```
int BigNumber = 2639;
int IndividualNumber[10];
int temp = BigNumber;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  int digit = temp % 10;             // Remainder on division by 10
  temp = temp / 10;
  IndividualNumber[i] = digit;
}
```

This will store up to 10 digits of a number in `IndividualNumber`, in reverse order.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem. If this did help you, please accept it as an answer.